# How to handle dynamic images in Mail Signature

Tags: html, outlook, vml

I have a web application which creates signature for the logged in user with the help of a predefined template. There is an image in the template which will change periodically. The users will copy the signature from the application and paste it in their Mail client to create Signature in their Mail clients.

The problem here is when the image in the template is updated.The updated image is not reflected in the Signature.It still shows the old image which was present at the time of creation.

I have verified the .htm file created and the image src is referred to a local folder instead of web url. A _files folder is created in /Roaming/Microsoft/Signatures folder and the image is referred from there.

I have tried to add VML code into but still it is referring to local folder

```
<!--[if !vml]> <v:shape id="_x0000_i1031" type="#_x0000_t75"
alt="someText" href="https://example.com" target="&quot;_blank&quot;"
style='width:375pt;height:60pt;z-index:-1;' o:button="t"><v:imagedata
o:href="https://example.com/image003.gif"/></v:shape><![endif]-->
```

Is there any way we can overcome this ?

Comment: Do you mean the new image is not shown in the existing messages that were already created? Or in the new messages created after the signature image was updated?

Comment: Hi Dmitry, The image is showing, but the image is not getting updated to the latest image.It is struck with the image that is available during Signature creation. What is happenig in this case is the image is referred to local folder(signatureName_files/image03) instead of the internet URL.